# How to make a React web discoverable

Tags: reactjs, web, sitemap, robots.txt

I have a react web page which is structured very simply:

1. Welcome page
2. Search trails page:
   Under the search trails page, there are many trails that can be found by filters, when clicking on one of the trails the view is expanded, and the URL is changed according to the chosen trail.

For example:

https://mywebsite/search-trails?trailInfo=trail1.json

https://mywebsite/search-trails?trailInfo=trail2.json
...
...

I tried setting all the trails inside the sitemap.txt, and also used the react-helmet but still only
https://mywebsite/search-trails is discovered.

My goal is that any trail will be discoverable by search engines such as Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome?hl=fr) and manage your website SEO directly in it.

Make sure the `built` version of react is deployed and not the development version.

Be aware that React is a SPA (Single Page Application), which is not the best technology for SEO.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Is there a way to create all the pages (automatically) for each trail, so it will be Multi Page React?
by the end, there are more than 20k trails, It doesn't make sense to create all of these pages.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think you can generate automaticaly this, since this is url parmaters